# Gwenview 20.04 snf 20.04.1 video is not playing

Tags: 20.04, video, phonon, gwenview

Gwenview used to play back mp4 video, but after 20.04 Ubuntu upgrade videos are no longer playing.

I tried installing these dependencies based on [the info found here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/gwenview-dragon-player-not-playing-video-just-sound-4175585042/), but got `E: Unable to locate package phonon-gstreamer-4.8.2-x86_64-1`

What is missing? How can I get Gwenview to play mp4 files again? (VLC Video player works)

Answer (score 0):

I just found Gwenview Version 19.12.3, and there the video is working.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post looking for a way to solve that same issue, and finally solved by installing `phonon4qt5-backend-vlc`

Dropping this here in case someone needs it :)